# How to make gitignore exception

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying to use the `.gitignore` to help me filter out folders. I need an inner-folder but not anything else in the folder which contains this inner-folder.

I tried this:

**.gitignore**

```
**/outer-folder
!inner-folder/
```

This does not seem to work. The entire outer-folder is gone. Why?

Also, I would appreciate if someone help me with a relevant question: Maybe the reason this does not work is because the `.gitignore` never get re-executed after I added these two lines of code. So how to force Git run `.gitignore`?

I tried `touch .gitignore` but some bash (e.g. vscode) does not know command `touch`. Any better solution?

Comment: Also, `.gitignore` never gets "executed".  Git will always use the current version of the file.  It may *seem* not to work if you are trying to ignore a file that is already tracked by git, in which case you have to `git rm --cached`.

Comment: `foo/` ignores `foo/` itself and everything underneath it. `foo/*` ignores everything underneath `foo/`. If `foo/` has been ignored, then nothing underneath it can be re-included. So what you need is `**/outer-folder/*`.

Comment: @0x5453 - Not a good duplicate. If you read the question, you'll see that OP already *tried* using `!` (the answer to the linked question); and indeed directory exclusions are something of a special case here, wherein that doesn't work.

Comment: @ElpieKay - Have you tested that solution?  Because in my tests (both previously when this has been discussed, and just now) it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you all. As @0x5453 mentioned, the solution is posted in the other question. I need to add `/*` after `outer-folder`